# Rapsbery Pi stretch lite not connecting to WiFi Network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, raspbian, wpa-supplicant

I am running the latest November release of Raspian Stretch Lite on my Pi.

I created a `/etc/network/interfaces` file with this information whenever I plug in my USB wifi dongle into the USB interface it connects to the appropriate network.

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    network 10.0.0.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.0.0.255

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 10.10.10.1
    gateway 10.10.10.1
    network 10.10.10.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.10.10.255

auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid "ssidssidssid"
    wpa-psk "pskpskpsk"
```

However, I need to be able to connect successfully to multiple networks, so doing a little research led me to [how do i set up networking wifi static ip address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address/37921#37921)

This one talks about leaving `/etc/network/interfaces` file alone, and making changes to only `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` or `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf` for stretch.

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    scan_ssid=1
    ssid="ssid1ssid1ssid1"
    psk="psk1psk1psk1"
    id_str="AP1"
}

network={
    scan_ssid=1
    ssid="ssid2ssid2ssid2"
    psk="psk2psk2psk2"
    id_str="AP2"
}
```

I had to `sudo systemctl enable wpa_supplicant` to enable wpa_supplicant and `sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant` since it was showing disabled on my build.

I have even tried rebooting after enabling this service.  But I am not showing an IP address from the access point using `ip address`.  Using `iwgetid` gets me nothing and `iwconfig` doesn't show it connecting either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get wpa_supplicant to work from the command line without it running as a service by using the man page example.

```
wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0
```

running it as a service and getting it to work required me to modify the Unit File of the wpa_supplicant.service

```
sudo systemctl edit --full wpa_supplicant.service
```

changing the execstart line to:

```
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf  -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
```

Still not exactly sure how to get all interfaces to use this .conf file but this got me working as a service.